# Detect change for multiple app instances when there are several logins

Tags: c++, windows

Suppose I created an app which runs by two users currently logon, with `user1` inactive and `user2` active, see below illustration (so there are two process exist simultaneously in system), the app will read/write a physical file, say adding some info to this file.

My question is, when `user2` adds some data to this file, after switching back to `user1`, how can `app inst1` knows about the change? (we can of course restart`app inst1` but it is not desirable).

One solution is let app handles session change event, in Windows there is a `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` which needs a `HWND` but my app is a console app.

Any ideas?

[image: illustration]

Comment: How about reading modification date when gathering the file and then comparing it when trying to save it?

Comment: @Pablo Lemurr thanks for the suggestion, but when to read modificaiton date?

Comment: First time when reading the file. Second time - when trying to write it. This will work if the lag between reading the date and comparing it is so little you can skip it (so while you are comparing the dates the other user would change the file).

Comment: @@Pablo Lemurr That's a feasible solution, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Windows API function FindFirstChangeNotification:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx

You register what conditions you want to be notified about (in your case, probably last update time) and get a handle which you can then wait on. You would, I guess, want to put this in a separate thread rather than blocking your main thread.